# Scrapy + selenium python авторизация вконаткте

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте, selenium, scrapy

У меня питон версии 3.6, scrapy 1.4. Нужно сделать авторизацию в вконтакте для парсинга моей странички. Пытался протестить примерную авторизацию на другом одностраничнике:

```
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(log_path=None,
                                    executable_path="/home/zik/Programms/Gekodriver/geckodriver")

    self.driver.get(self.start_urls[0])

    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Вход").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    log = self.driver.find_element_by_id("user[login]")
    psw = self.driver.find_element_by_id("user[password]")
    btn = self.driver.find_element_by_id("user[submit]")

    log.send_keys(LOGIN)
    psw.send_keys(PASSWORD)
    btn.click()

    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

    self.driver.close()

    return Request("https://www.livelib.ru/", cookies=cookies, callback=self.after_login)
```

После возраста новой странички авторизация не проходит. Пробовал через формы scrapy неудобно, так как много js на клиенте. Помогите, как совместить scrapy + selenium?

Comment: А какая ошибка?

Comment: не пробовали официальное  vk api использовать? Если хотите javascript выполнять в рамках scrapy, то есть splash.

Comment: vk api музыка закрыта.

Answer (score 0):

Одних куки может быть недостаточно, возможно есть всякие токены и прочее. Нужно изучать трафик общения клента и сервера (можно через инструменты разработчика в браузере), а затем воспроизводить все действия через scrapy.

Ну или использовать только Selenium, забирать содержимое страниц через него и далее парсить.

Comment: Через только селениум не могу, ссылка на аудио отдается аяксом и сразу загрузка аудио идем в html его нет, не знаю как спарсить.

Comment: @ВладЗикунов, руководство vk всеми силами пытается ограничить прослушивание музыки на их сайте, так что тут придется хорошенько постараться. Я бы попробовал реализовать через библиотеку requests. Открываешь мониторинг сети (в браузере инструменты разработчика), изучаешь запросы и пытаешься повторить.